# For-Loops in pyspark causes increasing dataframe size and failed job

Tags: apache-spark, for-loop, memory-management, pyspark

I have a for loop in my pyspark code. When I test the code on around 5 loops it works fine. But when I run it on my core dataset which results in 160 loops, my pyspark job (submitted on an EMR cluster) fails.  It first attempts it a second time before failing.

Below is a screenshot of the job runs in the Spark History Server:

[image]

The initial job `Attempt ID 1` was run at 4:13pm and 4 hours later a second attempt `Attempt ID 2` was done after which it failed. When I open up the jobs, I don't see any failed tasks or stages.
I am guessing it is because of the increasing size of the for loop.

Here is the stderr log of the output: It failed with status 1
[image]

Here is my pseudocode:

```
#Load Dataframe
df=spark.read.parquet("s3://path")
df=df.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK) # I will be using this df in the for loop
flist=list(df.select('key').distinct().toPandas()['key'])
output=[]

for i in flist:
    df2=df.filter(col('key)==i))
    Perform operations on df2 by each key that result in a dataframe df3
    output.append(df3)

final_output = reduce(DataFrame.unionByName, output)
```

I think the `output` dataframe increments in size that the job eventually fails.
I am running 9 worker nodes with 8 vCores with 50GB of memory in each node.

Is there a way to write the `output` dataframe to a check point after a set number of loops, clear the memory and then continue the loops from where it left off in Spark?

**EDIT:**
My expected output is like so:

```
key        mean   prediction
3172742   0.0448    1
3172742   0.0419    1
3172742   0.0482    1
3172742   0.0471    1
3672767   0.0622    2
3672767   0.0551    2
3672767   0.0406    1
```

I can use groupBy function because I am performing a kmeans clustering and it doesnt allow groupBy. So I have to iterate over each key to perform the kmeans clustering.

Comment: You should show the log.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish because you are taking the distinct keys and looping through that keys. Filtering the rows based on the key in the loop and again doing a union.. You should post some sample data and what the final output you are expecting.

Comment: @PhạmNgọcQuý I have added the log in my post
@NikunjKakadiya I need to loop by key because I am performing kmeans on each group of keys and it doesnt support `groupBy` method in spark